# HTML - make input field selectable but not changeable

Tags: html, text

Like the youtube embed text fields. How do you make a text field selectable but not changeable?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="Some Text" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that when analyzing the html of youtube. I thought it was somekind of js-solution, but apparently they use this technique too. Very simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this is just to make a div **appear** like a text field.

```
<div style="border: inset 2px #ccc;background:#fff;padding:2px;">
  http://example.com/?id=sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
</div>
```